# Is there a way to federete Cognito user pool with Keycloak

Tags: amazon-cognito, keycloak, federated-identity, federation

We have a Cognito user pool with customers from a different company. Our application needs to allow users to login and authorise API calls from our backend. We are looking for a way to federate Cognito user pool with Keycloak. By default Keycloak supports LDAP and Kebros. Is it possible to federate with the Cognito user pool?